# In Hybrid setup of O365 & Exchange how to differenciate users?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server, hybrid

I fetched users from O365 api. I got both users O365 & Exchange users. How I can fetch only O365 users using graph apis?

Or How we can differenciate users of o365 & exchange users?

Answer (score 0):

Are the Exchange Online users cloud only and the Exchange Server users synced from AD? If so, you can look at the various onPremises attributes available in the beta endpoint. If the account is synced from AD they will have values, if cloud they will be null.

For example, here's a cloud user:

```
"onPremisesDomainName": null,
    "onPremisesImmutableId": null,
    "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
    "onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
    "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
    "onPremisesUserPrincipalName": null,
```

Versus a synced user:

```
"onPremisesDomainName": "example.com",
    "onPremisesImmutableId": "khaeSOCUHOSUsCHUBVeqqQ==",
    "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": "2018-09-08T00:55:43Z",
    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": "S-1-5-21-3245132666-154143651436-123413245-12341234",
    "onPremisesSamAccountName": "jdoe",
    "onPremisesSyncEnabled": true,
    "onPremisesUserPrincipalName": "jdoe@example.com",
```